# TinyMCE - Stop formatting inside pre tag

Tags: html, tinymce, wysiwyg, pre

When i add plain text inside pre tag it's formatted( space changed to `&nbsp;` line-break to `<br />` and so on). When i add it in html view - all spaces and line-breaks are deleting too. It seems to me unnecessary.

How can i stop TinyMCE doing this, save original formatting inside `<pre>` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is formatted depending on your browser. You won't be able to change that- and if you are you shouldn't do it.
In Firefox the `br`-element is necessary to be able to click inside the html element, so is the `&nbsp;`.

Spaces added in html view at the end or beginning of a html-element get removed (trimmed out) by default - that is correct btw.